# What are some of your favorite flying and piloting related lessons or concepts to share with your non-pilot friends?

Tags: general-aviation

My team at work is doing this thing where each person teaches something new every week. I want to teach them about flying (I'm a private pilot). I'm curious what you think are topics that people find interesting.

I want to skip explaining the physics/aerodynamics but instead focus on some lessons or concepts that can be transferred to other things in life.

For e.g

- how everything is designed with safety / redundancy in mind,
- single pilot resource management
- checklists

What are some other cool ideas?

Comment: While interesting, your question is opinion based and therefore off topic.

Comment: Hi, welcome to aviation. While this question is not on topic on the main site you might well find some people interested in this in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar)

Answer (score 3):

There exists a machine with which you can casually swim through the atmosphere to explore mountain tops, deep canyons, and vast expanses.  You need no special degree or unusual intellect to use it.  In fact, morons do it!  A little over 100 years ago it would have been called magic.  Today they are so common that many consider them a nuisance or necessary inconvience.

One type (there are A LOT of different types) is a million pound machine that can carry 500 people seven miles above the earth at 85% the speed of sound and cross entire oceans in mere hours.  How do you just not fall to your knees, mouth agape, in awe of such a thing??

Oh...because there are so many of them, and they're so safe, and so cheap to use that anyone with a few hundred dollars can bum a ride to anywhere on the planet while garbed in clothing a notch above underwear.

The fact is that we are living in SciFi land from the perspective of someone three generations ago.

And that's just airplanes.